# how to properly read Nordic alphabets like Ø

Tags: r, alphabet

I just started data analysis with R and the dataset I'm currently working with reads `Cédric` as `C<e9>dric`.
What's a way I can get read all names perfectly without having to correct them individually?

Comment: How exactly are you importing these datasets? What OS are you using? It's easier to help you if you provide a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Comment: Importing data set with read.csv, Names appear as appropriate on excel e.g   "Álvaro Fernández"  but after import and viewing in R studio, the name is shown as "<c1>lvaro Fern<e1>ndez".  I am using a windows 11

Comment: Do you know what encoding was used in the file? On windows you might see both Latin-1 and UTF-8 as pretty common, though with other languages different encodings may have been used. What version of R are you using? Windows support for UTF-8 changed a lot in R 4.2. Sometimes the value is just escaped when printing to the R console. If you `cat()` the value in the column you can see the unescaped version. It's really hard to guess what might work in your case with a proper reproducible example we can copy/paste to test with.

Comment: I do not know what encoding was used on the file. R studio version 4.2.1 is what I'm using. Yeah, it's difficult as I'm not giving you enough to work with.